# Junit Tests pass individually but fail when run together

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently working on an assignment for school and I'm struggling with the testing portion.  For some reason the unit tests run fine when run individually but not when run together.  I know this has something to do with me sharing the object between them when I shouldn't be based on my prior searches, but I can not for the life of me figure out what needs to be changed to remedy this problem.  The code is below for both the AppointmentService class as well as the AppointmentServiceTest class.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for some time now and know it's probably something that someone else will see immediately.

The AppointmentServiceTest class

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.text.ParseException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import main.Appointment;
import main.AppointmentService;

class AppointmentServiceTest {

    private static AppointmentService appointmentService;
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        appointmentService = AppointmentService.getService();
    }
    
    @Test
    void testAddAppointmentSuccess() throws ParseException {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");
        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment));
        
        Appointment cachedAppointment = appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment.getAppointmentId());
        
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment != null);
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment.getAppointmentId().equals("123456"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment.getAppointmentDate().equals("2022-10-01"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment.getAppointmentDescription().equals("Appointment Description String")); 
    }
    
    @Test
    void testAddMultipleAppointmentsSuccess() throws ParseException {
        Appointment appointment1 = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");
        Appointment appointment2 = new Appointment("1234567", "2022-10-02", "Appointment Description String2");
        
        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment1));
        Appointment cachedAppointment1 = appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment1.getAppointmentId());
        
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment1 != null);
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment1.getAppointmentId().equals("123456"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment1.getAppointmentDate().equals("2022-10-01"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment1.getAppointmentDescription().equals("Appointment Description String"));    
        
        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment2));
        Appointment cachedAppointment2 = appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment1.getAppointmentId());
        
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment2 != null);
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment2.getAppointmentId().equals("1234567"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment2.getAppointmentDate().equals("2022-10-02"));
        assertTrue(cachedAppointment2.getAppointmentDescription().equals("Appointment Description String2"));
        
    }
    
    @Test
    void testAddAppoitnmentDuplicateIdFail() throws ParseException {
        Appointment appointment1 = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");
        Appointment appointment2 = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");


        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment1));
        assertFalse(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment2));
    }
    
    @Test
    void testGetAppointmentAndUpdateSuccess() throws ParseException {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");
        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment));
        
        Appointment updatedAppointment = appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment.getAppointmentId());
        updatedAppointment.setAppointmentDate("2022-10-02");
        updatedAppointment.setAppointmentDescription("New Description");
        
        updatedAppointment = appointmentService.getAppointment(updatedAppointment.getAppointmentId());
        
        assertTrue(updatedAppointment.getAppointmentDescription().equals("New Description"));
        assertTrue(updatedAppointment.getAppointmentDate().equals("2022-10-02"));
    }
    
    @Test
    void testGetAppointmentAndDeleteSuccess() throws ParseException {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment("123456", "2022-10-01", "Appointment Description String");
        
        assertTrue(appointmentService.addAppointment(appointment));
        
        appointment = appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment.getAppointmentId());
        assertTrue(appointment != null);
        
        assertTrue(appointmentService.deleteAppointment(appointment.getAppointmentId()));
        assertTrue(appointmentService.getAppointment(appointment.getAppointmentId()) == null);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testDeleteInvalidAppointmentFail() {
        String invalidAppointmentIdString = "123";
        
        assertFalse(appointmentService.deleteAppointment(invalidAppointmentIdString));
    }
```

And the AppointmentService Class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AppointmentService {

    private static AppointmentService reference = new AppointmentService();
    private final Map<String, Appointment> appointmentList;
    
    AppointmentService() {
        this.appointmentList = new HashMap<String, Appointment>();
    }
    
    public static AppointmentService getService() {
        return reference;
    }
    
    public boolean addAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        
        if(!appointmentList.containsKey(appointment.getAppointmentId())) {
            appointmentList.put(appointment.getAppointmentId(), appointment);
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
    
    public boolean deleteAppointment(String appointmentId) {
        return appointmentList.remove(appointmentId) != null;
    }
    
    public Appointment getAppointment(String appointmentId) {
        return appointmentList.get(appointmentId);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using same `appointmentService` instance for your 2 test and adding the appointment with same id ("123456") in your 2 test. So, when tests are ran together, you next test will always fail as you are assuming that the id "123456" is not present in second test, but it is.

You should create a new `appointmentService` for each test as unit test = test in isolation, especially when your testing instance has some states.

Comment: One way to do this is to use a `@BeforeEach` annotation on the setup method which creates the `AppointmentService`.

Comment: So I assumed that was the case and switched the ```@BeforeAll``` to ```@BeforeEach``` and at that point the tests did not run at all.  Am I missing something for that to work correctly?

Comment: Do this in your @BeforeAll `appointmentService = new AppointmentService()`. Also remove the `reference` field and `getService` method. They are useless and is also a bad practice.

Comment: I removed both the reference and the getService method and was able to run my tests successfully.  I used the singleton due to it being how a previous assignment approached a similar problem and me unfortunately approaching this one the same way. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove static in here

```
private static AppointmentService appointmentService;\
```

And fot setUp method too. Also change @BeforeAll to @BeforeEach it will make create new appointmentService for each test to isolate test cases.

Also if there is no any reason to have reference as static then class itself it's better to refactor (get rid of static reference) self-made singleton is kind of anti-pattern.
Now when code calls getReference it returns always the same instance, that's why it does not work while running all tests.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
I hope it helps

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I'm still running into the same issue, all tests pass when ran alone, but when run together I get 4 failures.

Comment: The reason is private STATIC AppointmentService reference = new AppointmentService(); staic in calls (not test).  Since it is statijc you have the same reference for each test in suite. Any particular reason it is static? I can guess you want just a singleton, it does not look like usual singleton. If there is not any reason to have self-made singleton (it is antipattern by the way) make just refacror code itself (get rid of static field reference)

Comment: Thank you  very much for all the feedback and advice.  The reason I had used static and created the singleton was because that is how my professor coded the solution to the last assignment which is very similar so I assumed I would approach this problem the same way. I made the changes you suggested and I was able to process all of the tests successfully when ran together and independently.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use @beforeEach instead @beforeAll

```
@BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        appointmentService = AppointmentService.getService();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is unrelated to your exact issue, I've faced the same side effects and found the cause.

A part of the code is **comparing two Calendar objects with equals** that causes the JUnit test to fail when all class tests are running, and it succeeds when running in isolation.

It also works when I'm using

> @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)

And put the failing test method on position 1 in the class.

**As it is a legacy project, and we are stuck with Calendar for now, I'm at least converting it to LocalDate in this case to do the comparison without side effects.**